# ASP.NET Adding Javascript to page if page not secure

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm trying to add some share this javascript in between the head tags of an asp.net page but only if the page is not secure (!Request.IsSecureConnection). How do I get the code in the head tags to check for secure connection and then write the javascript if not secure. I've tried using <% %> blocks and RegisterStartupScriptBlock and it's not working

UPDATE:

Was able to get it to work using this in the Page_Load

```
if(!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
  Include.Attributes.Add("src", "http....");
  this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
}
```

Comment: You could post some specific code that you tried.  Simply saying "it's not working" isn't giving people much to go on.

Comment: This isn't much to post besides what I said already. I'm thinking someone has already done this before and doesn't need me to show code but it would be something like this <% if(!Request.IsSecureConnection { %> show javascript here <% } %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <% if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
       { %>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           onload = function() { 
                        alert('Page is not secure') };
       </script>
       <% } %>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{%>
    <script ..........> </script>
<%}%>
```

This didn't work?

**Update** From your comments this didn't work. I'm guessing it has to do with something you are doing in your code behind.  Did you try calling `RegisterClientScriptBlock` from your code behind?  If you could post your aspx and code behind we might be able to help more.

Comment: No. I get this error
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.; The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Put that stuff in the code-behind page instead of inline with the markup. Wrap a placeholder control or something similar around your script and show/hide the placeholder control based on secure connection or not.